# How to access the value of angularjs datetimrpicker in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have added a datetimepicker using angular-datetimepicker script.and i have added it successfully.but now i want to access the value of of this datetimepicker in ng-model and i have done like this.

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="end_date" ng-init="" datetime-picker date-only />
```

when i print data through json like {{end_date | json}} it gets the value of end_date but when i have updated this input field like this

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="submitAdsFormData.end_date" datetime-picker date-only />
```

and print data like {{submitAdsFormData | json}}..get a blank array as {}

Can anyone help me to get the value of datepicker inside ng-model ?
Please help me to get this.Any help will be appreciated.

I have initialize submitAdsFormData in angular controller like this.

Controller:

```
 $scope.submitAdsFormData = {};
```

and write function like this:

```
 $scope.add_jobs = function(){
Data.addJobs($.param($scope.submitAdsFormData,$scope.start_date,$scope.end_date)).success(function (data) {
           //write code  
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have `submitAdsFormData` initialized? Can you share your controller code?

Comment: Try to declare `submitAdsFormData` in your controller. $scope.submitAdsFormData ={}

Comment: @ Oluwafemi Sule...please take a look of my edited part.

Comment: You're sure about `<input type='text'`? Should not be `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: I have used script for adding datetimepicker in angular js